# If multiple entry types?

Tags: conditional, entry-type

Is it possible to do the following?

```
{% if entry.type == 'overview' %}

    {{ entry.title }}

{% elseif entry.type == ['availability', 'specifications', 'sitemap', 'location'] %}

    {{ entry.title }}

{% else %}

    {{ entry.title }}

{% endif %}
```

At the minute it is not returning anything inside the elseif, can anyone spot anything wrong with the logic or is there an alternative method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were so close! Instead of asking whether `entry.type` is equal to the array (which it isn't), you need to find out whether the value of `entry.type` matches one of the array items.

Here is an updated snippet that should work for you:

```
{% if entry.type == 'overview' %}
    {{ entry.title }}
{% elseif entry.type.handle in ['availability', 'specifications', 'sitemap', 'location'] %}
    {{ entry.title }}
{% else %}
    {{ entry.title }}
{% endif %}
```

---

**EDIT:**

It's important to recognize that `entry.type` is actually an *object*. When checking a value using `in`, the object's `__toString` method will not be invoked. Therefore you'll need explicitly specify `entry.type.handle` when testing whether the type is `in` an array.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe off topic, but if you are looking to have a lot of logic based around entry types, maybe its easier to have one template per entry type?

If you set your section to use the template "sectionName/_entry", that entry can contain the code:

```
{% include['sectionName/' ~ entry.type, 'sectionName/default'] %}
```

This way you can have a template per entry type, with a fallback to default.twig inside the "sectionName" folder (inside your template folder).

Now you could have a overview.twig and sitemap.twig etc.